# how to search for two consecutive cells that have 2 different values?

Tags: excel, search

Because I am working with a very large sheet of excel and i need to find in a specific column the last 1 before changing to 0.

is there a way to search for that ?
how to search for two consecutive cells that have 2 different values ?

Comment: Have you tried using a filter on the columns?

Comment: I see 2 different questions here, which one are you asking:  1) "I need to find in a specific column the last 1 before changing to 0".  Answer:  `=MATCH(0,A:A,0)-1`    2) "How to search for two consecutive cells that have 2 different values".  Answer:  see Isaac Moses response below.  which is it?

Comment: so i have used the following
=MATCH(0,F2:F41698,1)
I understand that
0 means this what we are searching for
going from F2 to F41698
1 means before we get to 1 (is this correct ?)

i don't understand what you wrote about -1 2 )

can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are in column A, put into B2:

```
= A2 = A1
```

Copy B2 and paste to the rest of column B, from B3 to next to the last value in column A.

Search column B for FALSE.